# POSTGRES COALESCE(NULLIF(c.name,''), 'unassigned') not working

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

No version of a character varying field will return anything but `NULL` if there isn't a value... it's really frustrating

`CASE WHEN COALESCE(NULLIF(e.name,''),'unassigned') IS NULL THEN 'unassigned' ELSE a.name END`

was my final test and it still simply returns `NULL`  unless the field has a value

it's character varying(255)

```
COALESCE(a.name,'unassigned') // won't work
NULLIF(a.name,'') // won't work
NULLIF(a.name,NULL) // won't work
COALESCE(NULLIF(a.name,''),'unassigned') // won't work
```

however the instant i use `0` it works..

what's up with that?

it's a character varying(255) field and it is set to default to null

as a matter of point the build of the table column is

```
name varying character(255) DEFAULT(NULL)
```

so I know it's entering NULL
and I've already done a

`SELECT * FROM <tbl> WHERE name IS NULL;` and of course, I return all the NULL rows with a.name... so what's the deal with this?

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? What is it returning and what do you expect it to return?

Comment: nullif(): `The NULLIF function returns a null value if value1 equals value2; otherwise it returns value1.`. if `a.name` is null, by DEFINITION it cannot ever be equal or unequal to `''`. a null value cannot ever be equal to anything, including itself. `null` is poisonous and make most operations involving it have null results as well. your nullif() would only work if `a.name` is literally an empty string.

Comment: well since COALESCE test for NULL and i am replacing it with 'unassigned' it is "not working' because no matter what, it always returns NULL

Comment: @MarcB hey yeah that I know, however coalesce is supose to test for `NULL` so because I know for a fact that the field value is `NULL` it should return `'unassigned'` which of course it doesn't... yet... when I use: `COALESCE(a.name,'0')` it returns `0` in the column, which is ridiculous. even when i force case to `::text` or `::character varying` it still returns `NULL` unless I use an integer... which is just retarded to me.  Of what value is converting a text/character varying field with an integer result as a string when it is clearly a string from the onset at column design?

Comment: @MarcB  Incidentally, although i didn't show it as one of my examples : i also tried `NULLIF(a.name,NULL) and it still returned `NULL` so as `nullif()` tests for `null` and i gave it a `null` to test against it should have then returned `null` for the coalesce(nullif(a.name,NULL),'undefined')` which it didn't... instead it returned `NULL`

Comment: I tried each of these out on 9.4 using `CREATE TABLE a ( name CHARACTER VARYING(255) DEFAULT(NULL), id integer);` with three test records (1 with a `name` value, 1 where I inserted an explicit `NULL`, and one where I inserted just an `id` so it would default to a `name` of `NULL`). Everything worked as expected. So... I'm no help at all.

Comment: @JNevill  it turns out that it's not going to work - it's a materialized_view creation with nested `SELECT a.*, (SELECT b.name from asset b where b.id = a.asset_id ) FROM asset_types a` where `b.id` would return `0` meaning that assets is returning no rows, and there is nothing to test, and as a result it must return `NULL`  because when i ran the query on the materialized view itself on the storedProc which calls inside that materialized view - it obviously returns no rows - hence NULL, but the query on that NULL will return 'unassigned'  I've clearly been coding too long today

Comment: I know the feeling. I come to SO to answer questions when I've been coding too long or I'm stuck on a problem. It really clears the mind to actually answer questions when your stuck on one yourself. Glad you figured it out! :)

Comment: The condition `COALESCE(NULLIF(e.name,''),'unassigned') IS NULL` is always false.

Comment: Just remove the silly CASE ... WHEN, and select the expression: `SELECT ..., COALESCE(NULLIF(e.name,''), 'unassigned') , ...`

Answer (score -1):

ok... to everyone deciding to answer me with:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(e.name,''),'unassigned') IS NULL...
```

This method will never work on a return of "no records" and as this is a stored procedure which creates a materialized view, where I'm polling via nested queries - where it is possible for a column to have `0` (as the default id = other_id) the nested query would simply return no rows. When no row is returned, the functions of `COALESCE` or `NULLIF` would never execute. A row would have to be returned in order for those functions to act upon the row values... As I've never heard of a table with a PK auto-incremented field starting at `0` and generally starting at `1` the resultset of "no records returned" will always return a NULL value into the materialized view column.

The query I run afterward to poll rows from that materialized view will however function properly as `COALESCE(etc etc)` because now there is an actual NULL value in that column.